# redocly-cli build command gives TypeError

Tags: github-actions, openapi, redocly

I am trying to integrate Redocly with GitHub Actions. For testing purposes I have created an `openapi.yaml` file like this. I also have created a couple of sample schemas to use in this file.

```
openapi: 3.1.0
info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: Example.com
  termsOfService: 'https://example.com/terms/'
  contact:
    email: contact@example.com
    url: 'http://example.com/contact'
  license:
    name: Apache 2.0
    url: 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html'
  x-logo:
    url: 'https://redocly.github.io/openapi-template/logo.png'
  description:
    $ref: ./info-description.md
tags:
  - name: Echo
    description: Example echo operations.
  - name: User
    description: Operations about users.
  - name: Tag
    description: This is a tag description.
  - name: Test
    description: This is a Test description.
servers:
  - url: 'https://{tenant}/api/v1'
    variables:
      tenant:
        default: www
        description: Your tenant id
  - url: 'https://example.com/api/v1'
paths:
  /users/{username}:
    $ref: 'paths/users_{username}.yaml'
  /echo:
    $ref: paths/echo.yaml
  /pathItem:
    $ref: paths/path-item.yaml
  /pathItemWithExamples:
    $ref: paths/path-item-with-examples.yaml
components:
  securitySchemes:
    main_auth:
      type: oauth2
      flows:
        implicit:
          authorizationUrl: 'http://example.com/api/oauth/dialog'
          scopes:
            'read:users': read users info
            'write:users': modify or remove users
    api_key:
      type: apiKey
      in: header
      name: api_key
    basic_auth:
      type: http
      scheme: basic
```

I also have created this `redocly.yaml` file:

```
# See https://redocly.com/docs/cli/configuration/ for more information.
apis:
  sample@v1: 
    root: openapi/openapi.yaml
extends:
  - recommended
rules:
  no-unused-components: error
features.openapi:
  htmlTemplate: ./docs/index.html
  theme:
    colors:
      primary:
        main: "#32329f"
  generateCodeSamples:
    languages:  # Array of language config objects; indicates in which languages to generate code samples.
      - lang: curl
      - lang: Node.js
      - lang: JavaScript
      - lang: PHP
      - lang: Python
```

Then I am trying to create a manual GitHub Action flow on my repository to publish this documentation whenever I run the job manually.B ut when I try to run the `redoc-cli build openapi.yaml` command in my script, I am getting the following error. (I also tried running this command on my terminal to see if I can get more error details, but I still get the same error.)

```
Found redocly.yaml and using features.openapi options
Prerendering docs
TypeError: this.description.search is not a function
    at new Ur (C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\redoc-cli\node_modules\redoc\bundles\redoc.lib.js:41:54995)
    at new To (C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\redoc-cli\node_modules\redoc\bundles\redoc.lib.js:41:81323)
    at new rc (C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\redoc-cli\node_modules\redoc\bundles\redoc.lib.js:1318:3218)
    at Module.<anonymous> (C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\redoc-cli\node_modules\redoc\bundles\redoc.lib.js:1318:2996)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at i (C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\redoc-cli\node_modules\redoc\bundles\redoc.lib.js:1318:2750)
```

Can anyone help me understand why this is happening and what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

The `redoc-cli` command is deprecated, so you could try building with the newer [redocly](https://github.com/Redocly/redocly-cli) tool. The `redocly build-docs` command is the one you want and should do what I think you expect here.